# Вопрос по вводу строк в структуру

Tags: c

Есть структура, в ней строка, в процессе выполнения программы она уже заполнена, но ввести её с клавиатуры не получается, ни *scanf* ни *gets*. Что я делаю не так?

```
struct Record                               
{
    int numberRecord;
    char *lastName;
    char *firstName;
    int month;
    int day;
    char *doctor;
};
void rand_likari(struct Record *pointer_numberRecord, int size)     
{
    char *doctors[10] = { "Терапевт","Хірург","Окуліст" };          
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        (*(pointer_numberRecord+i)).doctor= doctors[rand() % 3];
    }
}
int editList(struct Record *pointer_numberRecord, int size)
{
    struct Record *begin_Record = pointer_numberRecord;
    int number_Record = -1,true_digit=0;
    while (number_Record != 0)
    {

            rewind(stdin);
        true_digit = 0;
        pointer_numberRecord= begin_Record;
        number_Record = -1;
        printf("Введіть номер запису для редагування, або 0 для виходу:");
        scanf("%d", &number_Record);
        rewind(stdin);
        if (number_Record == 0)
        {
            return(0);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; pointer_numberRecord++, i++)
        {
            if (pointer_numberRecord->numberRecord == number_Record)
            {
                printf("%-3d %s %s %02d.%02d %s \n", pointer_numberRecord->numberRecord, pointer_numberRecord->lastName, pointer_numberRecord->firstName, pointer_numberRecord->month, pointer_numberRecord->day, pointer_numberRecord->doctor);
                true_digit++;
                printf("Редагувати #%d\n", pointer_numberRecord->numberRecord);

                printf("Введіть лікаря:");

                scanf("%s", pointer_numberRecord->doctor);//***ввод с строки клавиатуры***
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(true_digit==0)
            printf("Неіснуючий номер запису\n");
    }
}
void main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int menu = 1;
    struct Record mas[10], *recordPointer = mas;                    
    int size = sizeof(mas) / sizeof(struct Record);
        createNumber(mas,size);     
        rand_Date(mas, size);       
        randomAvatar(mas, size);    
        rand_likari(mas, size);      
    while (menu != 0)
    {
        menu = -1;
        //system("cls");
        printf("Операції з записами:\n1.Вивід на екран\n2.Редагуваня запису за номером\n3.Сортування записів за датою\n4.Сортування записів за алфавітом\n\n0.Вихід\n");
        printf("Введіть номер цифру операції:");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        rewind(stdin);
        switch (menu)
        {
        case 0:
            exit(0); break;
        case 1:
            showMass(mas, size); break;   //функция вывода на экран
        case 2:
        {
            while (editList(mas, size) != 0); //функция для ввода
        }break;
        default:
            menu = 3;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Пора в FAQ вносить...
Сбросьте буфер после ввода меню - в нем после считывания числа остается символ `\n`...

Например,

```
scanf( "%*[^\n]%*c" );
```

Присмотрелся - извините, у вас все гораздо хуже!

```
scanf("%s", pointer_numberRecord->doctor);//***ввод с строки клавиатуры***
```

**Куда** вы хотите считывать строку? Место не выделено. Сейчас указатель указывает на **литерал**, который является по определению константным и в который писать ничего нельзя, ибо Undefined Behaviour.

Если вы надеетесь *перезаписать* ваши строки "Терапевт" и иже с ними - даже и не надейтесь. Нет, какой-нибудь компилятор это сделает; другой на этом рухнет. VC++ сделает вид, что пишет, ничего не записав на самом деле - хотя, если отменить оптимизацию, то может и записать... UB на то и UB, что программа рушится только если везет. Вам не повезло :(

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно только перезаписать значение которое ему дали в функции rand_likari, через scanf и gets не вышло.

Comment: Посмотрите дополнение к ответу.